# Count data in JSON array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

If I create an SQL table like this:

```
ID  | Need  | Fulfill_User
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   3   | ["A","A","B"]
2   |   4   | ["B","C","A","B"]
3   |   2   | ["C","A"]
4   |   1   | ["D"]
```

Can I get a report like this?

1. A = 4
2. B = 3
3. C = 2
4. D = 1

Comment: Also if I understand that what you are asking, you are wanting to count items over multiple JSON arrays?

Comment: Is this what you want to do? https://dbfiddle.uk/Z2A88sf_ I'm not sure if I understand your question correct.

Answer (score 2):

The data in the `Fulfill_User` column is a valid JSON array, so if you use SQL Server 2016+, you simply need to parse this JSON and count the values with the appropriate `GROUP BY` clause:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 3, '["A","A","B"]'),
   (2, 4, '["B","C","A","B"]'),
   (3, 2, '["C","A"]'),
   (4, 1, '["D"]')
) v (ID, Need, Fulfill_User)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j.Fulfill_User, COUNT(*) AS Fulfill_User_Count
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.Fulfill_User) WITH (Fulfill_User varchar(1) '$') j
GROUP BY j.Fulfill_User
```